# window.open works different in chrome and firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, window.open

I want to open a new tab, if it has not been opened before.
If it has been already opened from the same opener, then show the tab (bring to front without reloading).

My code:

```
const openWindow = window.open(undefined, 'WindowName');

if (openWindow.location.href === 'about:blank') {
    openWindow.location.href = newWindowUrl;
}
```

In Chrome this will open a new tab and set the url.
Calling the same code again, will reopen the already available window, without reload.

In Firefox, this will open a new tab and set the url.
Calling the same code again, will do nothing.

How can I reopen the available window by window.name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for FireFox is:

```
const openWindow = window.open(undefined, 'WindowName');

if (openWindow.location.href === 'about:blank') {
    openWindow.location.href = newWindowUrl;
}

// ==> to open existing window in Firefox
openWindow.focus();
```